# Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: The string contains invalid characters

Tags: javascript, json, breeze

We had an issue with the `breeze.js saveChanges()`

when we we have multiple parent child relationship loaded it was throwing an exception: "Circular reference in value argument not supported"

I saw that some issue related to primitive types has been fixed on Breeze 1.4.7. I updated my codebase to use this version of Breeze.js and the circular reference error is gone now. However I still cannot save the record.

It throws `"Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: The string contains invalid characters."` now.

I believe there must be something wrong with my HTML, however it is huge and not easy to look for each element.

Can you please advise me a quick fix?

Comment: Also I don't understand why would json savebundle will have references to my DOM elements. As I understand it should just have all observables in my model without any relation to html document.

Comment: I would try to isolate the issue so that you can recreate it without a UI.  i.e. via a QUnit or Jasmine unit test. Many such 'bugs' turn out to be UI related and have nothing to do with breeze. If you can isolate it as a breeze issue, then we will fix it.

Comment: I agree and I also noted that it must be related my UI. I just wanted check on what circumstances breeze would behave like this, so that we can avoid and know what is the root of an issue.

Comment: BTW - we fixed this issue. in my model I have an object "A" which has navigation property of COLLECTOIN<B>. I also created a single object of type B which was loaded separately in my model which represents one of the object in COLLECION<B>. I removed this single B object and it started working for me.